# Diskutil & Bootcamp couldn't remove Windows 10 partition

Tags: hard-drive, windows, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I've installed windows 10 latest build on my mac using Boot Camp Assistant, And I'm trying to remove windows 10 now.

1. I've tried uninstall using Bootcamp Assistant but it could not recognize my windows installation.
   [image]

My windows works well and BitLocker is not enabled.

2. Then I tried Diskutil in terminal, `diskutil list` command output as below

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         180.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data                         60.7 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +180.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume                         91.6 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume                         82.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume                         529.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume                         1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume                         11.3 GB    disk1s5
```

Which windows is installed on disk0s3.
But when I tried `sudo diskutil eraseVolume free free disk0s3`, I encountered error below

```
Started erase on disk0s3
Unmounting disk
Error: -69879: Couldn't open disk
```

3. After above attemption, I've checked my Diskutil app and found below.

[image]

[image]

My total storage is about 256GB, and I could only see a 180GB partition under SSD.

What should I do to fully remove windows installation and restore my mac storage?
Thx in advance.

Comment: What is the current output from `diskutil list`.

Comment: The same as above [2], nothing changed and I can still see Microsoft Basic Data partition @DavidAnderson

Comment: Have you tried starting up in [Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255), and running Disk Utility from there? It may be worth trying.